# Opengl previous object disappears

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

When I make 2 or more instance of TestLine class and add it in the render class, only the last one is rendered. The previous objects doesn't render or disappear

TestLine class:

```
void update(){
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, xbo);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, verts.size());
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

void set(float x, float y, float x2, float y2){
    verts.push_back(x);
    verts.push_back(y);
    verts.push_back(x2);
    verts.push_back(y2);

   glGenBuffers(1, &xbo);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, xbo);
   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), &verts[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

functions in render class

```
void draw(){
    int size = lines.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        lines[i]->update();
}
void add(TestLine* d){
    lines.push_back(d);
}
```

Comment: Is this about desktop OpenGL or OpenGL ES?

Comment: I want it to run in both, opengl and gles1.x

Comment: Post the entirety of the `TestLine` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, xbo);
```

`GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` is not a valid argument for [`glBindBuffer()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBindBuffer.xml):

> `target`: Specifies the target to which the buffer object is bound. The symbolic constant **must be** `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`, or `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`.

Use `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` like in your other invocation.

---

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, verts.size());
```

`set()` only specifies *two* vertices, not four.  If `verts` contained some sort of multi-float `struct` (e.g.: `struct Vertex { float x, y; };`) instead of raw `float`s this would have worked.

Try this:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, verts.size() / 2);
```

Comment: I've been into this for a whole day and didn't even notice I put GL_VERTEX_ARRAY as argument for glBindBuffer()..maybe because it still renders 1 line.. -_- Thanks.